# Vaadin missing icons of all components

Tags: icons, vaadin, font-awesome, vaadin-valo-theme

We use the Vaadin valo-theme and component icons like the arrow of the combobox or the icon of the datefield are missing. We tried to put font-awesome manually, but the icons are still missing. We can't explain why.

Can somebody help?

My log output is full with stuff like this:

```
INFORMATION: Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/valo/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

I'm not sure if its related to our problem.

Instead of the icons there are just this signs
[image: Instead of the icons there are just this signs]

Comment: Does the server log shows some files not found 404 errors?
What does the webbrowser has for image URL's when you reference them?

Comment: The OpenSans-Light font has nothing to do with the icons. But the error suggest that you have a general problem with the css and resources. Did you deploy it correctly, including all required elements?

Comment: We tryed to replace all our theme recources with those from the valo demo from the git reposatory and it still doesn't work. Do you know an other example we could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the Java version of the project form `1.7` to `1.6`. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same problem.

We are using Wildfly 8.2 to deploy the application. The problem occured by enabling GZip compression for the server (following this blog post: [How to enable GZIP compression in Wildfly 8.2](http://dimaki.blogspot.de/2014/12/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in.html)).

Disabling it made everything work again. Currently I am still investigating why this is a problem.

Comment: JDC, did you found te solution for this? I have same issue. Is it possible to solve it without disabling gzip? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not. We did just disable it as it was an internal mini-application and did not have a major impact.